# Angular: Testing Directive with Jest

Tags: angular, angular-directive, ts-jest

I have a directive, which allows an input field to accept only digits. But how can I test if this directive works the way it should? I'm using Jest as testing framework, but a suggestion based on Jasmine would be helpful as well.
I thought to *simulate* pressing keys or simply setting the value of the input, but neither worked.

The directive:

```
@Directive({
  selector: '[digitsOnly]'
})
export class DigitsOnlyDirective {

  constructor(private _el: ElementRef) {
  }

  @HostListener('input', ['$event']) onInputChange(event: any) {
    const initialValue = this._el.nativeElement.value;
    this._el.nativeElement.value = initialValue.replace(/[^0-9]*/g, '');

    if (initialValue !== this._el.nativeElement.value) {
      event.stopPropagation();
    }
  }
}
```

My current test:

```
describe('DigitsOnlyDirective', () => {
  let debugElement: DebugElement;
  let fixture: ComponentFixture<TestComponent>;

  @Component({
    selector: 'my-test-component',
    template: `
        <div>
            <input digitsOnly/>
        </div>`
  })
  class TestComponent {
  }

  beforeEach(waitForAsync(() => {
    TestBed.configureTestingModule({
      declarations: [TestComponent, DigitsOnlyDirective]
    }).compileComponents();
  }));

  beforeEach(() => {
    fixture = TestBed.createComponent(TestComponent);
    fixture.detectChanges();

    debugElement = fixture.debugElement.query(
      By.directive(DigitsOnlyDirective)
    );
  });

  it('is created', () => {
    expect(fixture).toBeTruthy();
    expect(debugElement).toBeTruthy();
  });
});
```

Comment: Have you tried firing an input event against the input? I have a very similar directive and I managed to test it with TestingLibrary's `userEvent.type` function

Comment: If you query the input's native element you can set the value first and then call `.dispatchEvent(new Event('input'))` which would trigger your directive.

Comment: Thank you two very much. The first suggestion worked here. I already tried the second one, but I'm not sure, if I did it correctly.